# setting ulimit on a running process

Tags: debug, ulimit

I launched a server application and I want to run it for a long time for testing purpose. Unfortunately, I forgot to set before `ulimit -c unlimited` to catch an eventual crash and inspect it. Is there something I can do?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

On recent versions of Linux (since 2.6.36), you can use the [`prlimit`](http://karelzak.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/prlimit1.html) command and system call to set resource limits on an arbitrary process (given appropriate permissions):

```
$ prlimit --core=unlimited: --pid $$
$ prlimit --core --pid $$
RESOURCE DESCRIPTION             SOFT      HARD UNITS
CORE     max core file size unlimited unlimited blocks
```

You need util-linux-2.21 for the prlimit command, but you should be able to throw together a quick program to invoke the [prlimit system call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) otherwise:

```
int prlimit(pid_t pid, int resource, const struct rlimit *new_limit, struct rlimit *old_limit);
```

If you don't have a new enough version of Linux (or another OS) the only fix I'm aware of is to connect to the process with `gdb` and issue `setrlimit` from the debugger:

```
$ gdb -p $PID
...
(gdb) set $rlim = &{0ll, 0ll}
(gdb) print getrlimit(9, $rlim)
$1 = 0
(gdb) print *$rlim
$2 = {-1, -1}
(gdb) set *$rlim[0] = 1024*1024
(gdb) print setrlimit(9, $rlim)
$3 = 0
```

This is for setting `ulimit -m`, `RLIMIT_AS = 9`; exactly the same applies for `ulimit -c` (`RLIMIT_CORE`, numeric value `4` on Linux on x86-64).  For "unlimited", use `RLIM_INFINITY`, usually `-1`.  You should check in `/usr/include/bits/types.h` what the size of `rlim_t` is; I'm assuming `long long` (it's actually unsigned, but using a signed type makes "unlimited" -1 easier to read).

Comment: +1 The `gdb` technique is really cool. One caveat, it seems you [can't increase the number of open files for a non-root process](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getrlimit.html) past its hard limit, the `setrlimit` call returns -1, and errno is 22 (invalid argument).

Answer (score 3):

As Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty has no util-linux-2.21 (it is 2.20), there is no `prlimit` CLI command to use.

Using [Python3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html#resource.prlimit)+ (which is available on Ubuntu 14.04 and all later versions) can set resource limit for a running process. Run as root:

1-liner:

```
# PID=966
# grep 'open file' /proc/$PID/limits
Max open files            1024                 4096                 files     
# python3 -c "import resource; resource.prlimit($PID, resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE, (2048, 12345))"
# grep 'open file' /proc/$PID/limits
Max open files            2048                 12345                files
```

Or more verbose:

```
# python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 28 2017, 16:41:13) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import resource
>>> import os
>>> resource.prlimit(os.getpid(), resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE)
(1024, 4096)
>>> resource.prlimit(os.getpid(), resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE, (1369, 9999))
(1024, 4096)
>>> resource.prlimit(os.getpid(), resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE)
(1369, 9999)
```

Verify it works:

```
# grep 'open file' /proc/1472/limits 
Max open files            1369                 9999                 files
```

Note this works with Linux 2.6.36 or later with glibc 2.13 or later.